# Why won't Delphi XE2 let me embed a font resource as RCDATA?

Tags: delphi, fonts, ide, delphi-xe2, embedded-resource

I would like to embed a `.ttf` font resource into my EXE and dynamically load it. This particular method expects the resource to be of type `RCDATA`. So, I go to `Project > Resources and Images...` press `Add...`, and pick my `.ttf` file. The resource type `FONT` is automatically selected with an identifier of just `1`. I change the type to to `RCDATA` and type in my own resource name.

Problem: When I press `Ok` I get an error that the identifier of a `FONT` resource must be a numeric value. But it wasn't `FONT` type anymore, I had changed it to `RCDATA`.

How do I get past this problem?

Comment: I can't imagine why anyone would do anything other than use an rc file

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well, I do, I just let the IDE create it for me :-)

Comment: Why would you do that? The IDE sucks at this. It's a one liner in the rc file.

Comment: Along the lines of David's comment, I can't imagine why anyone would be working in the XE2 IDE.  It was horribly buggy.  XE was very good, and the last few versions are a lot more stable, but the first few releases after XE were essentially b0rked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(asking and answering together because I'm sure others have seen this problem)

It seems to be just a small bug in the IDE. When you first select your `.ttf` file in this resource screen, change the type, press `Ok` without changing the identifier (leave it `1`). Then, open the same screen back up, change the identifier to your own, and press `Ok`. It only works if you close and re-open the `Resources and Images` screen.

You could of course also write your own `.rc` file and do everything manually without this screen.

Comment: This bug is present and highly visible already in D2009. I find it strange that it hasn't been fixed in XE2.

Comment: I've always made .rc files by hand, but +1 for putting the IDE how-to up here.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Jerry says, you can simply "load" the font file in the `Resources and Images...` dialog. Once you selected it, you can change the type to `RCDATA` (combobox an the lower right) and if you have done that, you can change the name to whatever valid name you choose.

**There is no need to close and re-open the dialog**.

I tried this in XE2 and in XE7, and it works as expected. The `FONT` type is merely the default for, well, font files. That can easily be changed in the dialog.

This doesn't look like a bug to me. Just plain default behaviour when you load a font file. Just like there is default behaviour when you load a `.pas` file in the editor.

---

If you want to use an `.rc` file, it is quite easy to generate one in the editor (new text file with extension `.rc`) and then you can add it to your project. The IDE will take care of the rest. No need to do anything manually there either, except of course editing the `.rc` file.